# While Download Works But Post Request Not (Chilkat)

Tags: vb.net, http, post, chilkat

I am facing a very wired issue, and passed so many hours to find the issue but without any luck :(

i have setup a web server on my mobile (android)..

and trying to use that using my vb application

where i simple call Download method on the very sample url (same ip/port), it works and save the response body as downloaded file.

but when i try to send post command it is not working, it gives error "Connection rejected"

**here is the code to download:**

```
objDHTTP.Download("http://192.168.1.101:8000/fileAdmin.php", strAppDir & "\wtf-response.txt")
```

**here is the code when i tried to use same url and port for post request:**

```
objDRequest.Path = "/fileAdmin.php"
objDRequest.AddParam("fileAction", "Upload")
objDRequest.AddParam("fileName", "DB.sql")
objDRequest.AddFileForUpload("adminFile", strAppDir & "\c.dll")
objDResponse = objDHTTP.SynchronousRequest(strServerIP, 8000, False, objDRequest)
```

but it does not works and throws above error

**here is the success response (for download method):**

```
<ChilkatLog>
  <Download>
    <DllDate>Dec 21 2018</DllDate>
    <ChilkatVersion>9.5.0.76</ChilkatVersion>
    <Architecture>Little Endian; 32-bit</Architecture>
    <Language>.NET 4.0</Language>
    <VerboseLogging>0</VerboseLogging>
    <url>http://192.168.1.101:8000/fileAdmin.php</url>
    <toLocalPath>G:\wtf-sucess.txt</toLocalPath>
    <currentWorkingDir>G:\</currentWorkingDir>
    <a_httpDownload>
      <httpDownloadFile>
        <localFilePath>G:\wtf-sucess.txt</localFilePath>
        <localFileAlreadyExists>1</localFileAlreadyExists>
        <quickHttpRequest>
          <httpVerb>GET</httpVerb>
          <url>http://192.168.1.101:8000/fileAdmin.php</url>
          <openHttpConnection>
            <info>Opening connection directly to HTTP server.</info>
            <httpHostname>192.168.1.101</httpHostname>
            <httpPort>8000</httpPort>
            <tls>False</tls>
            <info>HTTP connection succeeded.</info>
          </openHttpConnection>
          <buildQuickRequest>
            <genStartLine>
              <startLine>GET /fileAdmin.php HTTP/1.1</startLine>
            </genStartLine>
            <addCookies>
              <info>Not auto-adding cookies.</info>
              <sendCookies>1</sendCookies>
              <cookieDir></cookieDir>
            </addCookies>
          </buildQuickRequest>
          <sendRequestHeader>
            <sendHeaderElapsedMs>0</sendHeaderElapsedMs>
          </sendRequestHeader>
          <statusCode>200</statusCode>
          <statusText>OK</statusText>
          <checkCloseConnection>
            <info>Response includes connection:close header (or proxy-connection:close header)</info>
          </checkCloseConnection>
        </quickHttpRequest>
        <outputLocalFileSize>26</outputLocalFileSize>
        <numOutputBytesWritten>26</numOutputBytesWritten>
      </httpDownloadFile>
    </a_httpDownload>
    <totalElapsedMs>47</totalElapsedMs>
    <ContentLength>0</ContentLength>
    <info>Success.</info>
  </Download>
</ChilkatLog>
```

**And here is the error/fail response (for post request):**

```
<ChilkatLog>
  <SynchronousRequest>
    <DllDate>Dec 21 2018</DllDate>
    <ChilkatVersion>9.5.0.76</ChilkatVersion>
    <Architecture>Little Endian; 32-bit</Architecture>
    <Language>.NET 4.0</Language>
    <VerboseLogging>0</VerboseLogging>
    <domain>191.168.1.101</domain>
    <port>8000</port>
    <ssl>0</ssl>
    <httpRequest>
      <httpVersion>1.1</httpVersion>
      <verb>POST</verb>
      <path>/fileAdmin.php</path>
      <contentType>multipart/form-data</contentType>
      <charset>windows-1252</charset>
      <sendCharset>0</sendCharset>
      <mimeHeader></mimeHeader>
      <requestParams>
        <requestItem>
          <name>fileAction</name>
          <value>Upload</value>
        </requestItem>
        <requestItem>
          <name>fileName</name>
          <value>DB.sql</value>
        </requestItem>
        <requestItem>
          <name>adminFile</name>
          <fileOnDisk>G:\c.dll</fileOnDisk>
          <numValueBytes>8697</numValueBytes>
        </requestItem>
      </requestParams>
    </httpRequest>
    <fullRequest>
      <a_synchronousRequest>
        <generateRequestHeader>
          <httpRequestGenStartLine>
            <genStartLine>
              <startLine>POST /fileAdmin.php HTTP/1.1</startLine>
            </genStartLine>
          </httpRequestGenStartLine>
          <addCookies>
            <info>Not auto-adding cookies.</info>
            <sendCookies>1</sendCookies>
            <cookieDir></cookieDir>
          </addCookies>
          <genMultipartFormData>
            <requestParam>
              <name>fileAction</name>
            </requestParam>
            <requestParam>
              <name>fileName</name>
            </requestParam>
            <requestParam>
              <name>adminFile</name>
              <filename>G:\c.dll</filename>
            </requestParam>
          </genMultipartFormData>
        </generateRequestHeader>
        <fullHttpRequest>
          <domain>191.168.1.101</domain>
          <port>8000</port>
          <ssl>0</ssl>
          <openHttpConnection>
            <info>Opening connection directly to HTTP server.</info>
            <httpHostname>191.168.1.101</httpHostname>
            <httpPort>8000</httpPort>
            <tls>False</tls>
            <socket2Connect>
              <connect2>
                <connectSocket>
                  <connect_ipv6_or_ipv4>
                    <info>Connection attempt failed.</info>
                    <maxWaitTimeMs>10000</maxWaitTimeMs>
                    <totalMsWaitedSoFar>2100</totalMsWaitedSoFar>
                  </connect_ipv6_or_ipv4>
                  <connect_ipv6_or_ipv4>
                    <info>Connection attempt failed.</info>
                    <maxWaitTimeMs>10000</maxWaitTimeMs>
                    <totalMsWaitedSoFar>2150</totalMsWaitedSoFar>
                  </connect_ipv6_or_ipv4>
                </connectSocket>
                <ConnectFailReason>Connection rejected</ConnectFailReason>
                <error>A few possible causes for a connection being rejected are:</error>
                <error>- A firewall (software or hardware), such as Windows Firewall, is blocking the connection .</error>
                <error>- Nothing is listening at the remote host:port</error>
              </connect2>
            </socket2Connect>
          </openHttpConnection>
        </fullHttpRequest>
        <success>0</success>
      </a_synchronousRequest>
      <success>0</success>
    </fullRequest>
    <totalTime>Elapsed time: 4390 millisec</totalTime>
    <error>Failed.</error>
  </SynchronousRequest>
</ChilkatLog>
```

can any one tell me what could be the reason for this?

thanks in advance

best regards

Comment: I even tried to change server, this one work better on browser than previous one but still same error on chilkat. so, it seems something wrong with chilkat not the server. Am i missing setting any value?

Answer (score 0):

The likely reasons are present in the LastErrorText:

```
            <ConnectFailReason>Connection rejected</ConnectFailReason>
            <error>A few possible causes for a connection being rejected are:</error>
            <error>- A firewall (software or hardware), such as Windows Firewall, is blocking the connection .</error>
            <error>- Nothing is listening at the remote host:port</error>
```

My guess is that the Windows Firewall is blocking the outbound POST.

This example shows the errors one would get for various TCP socket connection problems:  https://www.example-code.com/vbnet/socket_connect_fail.asp